# Python: Odd behavior with modulo operator

Tags: python, fibonacci

The solution is probably rather simple, but I just can't figure it out. Here is the code, it's a simple fibonacci number generator. The goal is to sum up all even fibonacci numbers below 4,000,000.

My approach is to first generate all fibonacci numbers below 4,000,000, and then either:
a) generate a new list ("even") with the even ones (this works fine)
b) removing the odd ones from the list "all"

However, in the latter case, the output is, for reasons I don't understand, this:
[2, 5, 8, 21, 34, 89, 144, 377, 610, 1597, 2584, 6765, 10946, 28657, 46368, 121393, 196418, 514229, 832040, 2178309, 3524578]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
all = []
even = []

def fibonacci():
    a, b = 1, 2
    while a < 4000000:
        all.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    print all

##Putting all the even fibonacci numbers in a different list and summing them up works fine
#    for i in all:
#        if i % 2 == 0:
#            even.append(i)
#    print even                   
#    print sum(even)


# But for some strange reason I can't figure out how to remove the odd numbers from the list
    for i in all:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            all.remove(i)

    print all
    print sum(all)

fibonacci()
```

Comment: I suggest you don't use "all" as a variable name.  There's a very useful builtin called [all](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) and it's really handy.

Comment: DSM, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Also, if anyone wonders about the fibonacci sequence: Yes, it normally starts with 0, 1, 1, 2, ... but the Project Euler instructions for this problem have it start with 1, 2, ...

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answers below! I think I learnt a lot from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "gotcha" situation: you're removing items from a list while iterating the list, thus changing the list, causing your iteration to behave unexpectedly.  Try this:

```
...
# But for some strange reason I can't figure out how to remove the odd numbers from the list
    for i in all[:]:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            all.remove(i)
...
```

This is what's called "slice" notation, and causes you to iterate a throwaway copy of the list  so that your iteration is not affected by the all.remove() calls.

Comment: An alternate solution that's more succinct, arguably clearer and at least as efficent (as you copy the whole list) is filtering to produce a new list: `all = [x for x in all if x % 2 == 0]`.

Comment: Yep, the list comprehension looks good, and I'd probably write it that way if I wrote the code myself.  I'd vote it up if you wrote it as an answer!  However, I usually find that my answers are more useful to the asker the more closely they resemble the question, so my SO style is to make a minimum diff to the question to make it behave correctly.

Comment: matt,
thank you very much for the explanation. Also, I do find your modification to my original code much more easily understandable than the solution of delnan. While delnan's code may be clearer for a seasoned Python developer, it's a bit too concise for me. I've made a note though. In a few months, I may prefer it as well...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove items from a list you iterate over. Python uses iterators, which only know the current index relative to the start of the list. When you remove items from the front of the list, the position of all elements change and you skip the next element.

You can avoid the problem in plenty ways, for example with generators:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 1, 2
    while a < 4000000:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def even(seq):
    for item in seq:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            yield item

print sum(even(fibonacci()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we closely observe how the iteration happens in the following code

```
for i in all:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            all.remove(i)

            # Add these two lines for debugging.. 
            # Or to know how this iteration functions

            print "when %d: " %i 
            print all

    print "Remaining Evens",
    print all
```

This is how the output would look like if the maximum number is 100.

```
original series [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
when 1: 
[2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
when 3: 
[2, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
when 13: 
[2, 5, 8, 21, 34, 55, 89]
when 55: 
[2, 5, 8, 21, 34, 89]
Remaining Evens [2, 5, 8, 21, 34, 89]
```

Here when python starts iterating a list, it technically remembers only the position of the number from which it has to iterate..

If we observe the output,

In the first iteration, it removes 1.

In the next iteration, it remembers that it has to count 2nd position. Now the list starts from "2". So the second position is "3". Thus it removes it.

In the next iteration, it remembers that it has to count from 3rd position. Now in the current list, the 3rd position is "8". So, it counts from there.. NOT from "5". So, as 8 doesn't satisfy, it goes to 13..

Thus, its skipping all those numbers..

How to fix this:

Actually, you need to make a copy of the "all" list and iterate. (It shouldn't refer to the same object..). If it does, the same thing happens.

you could do that by simply using slice operators:

```
copy_all= all[:] 

#or else, you need to use deepcopy()

import copy
copy_all = copy.deepcopy(all)

# you iterate copy_all but delete in all. 

However, prefer the first method. Its very simple.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you remove item at index i not a digit "i".

Comment: I don't believe that's true.  `Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 14 2011, 19:37:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> foo.remove(5)
>>> foo
[4, 3, 2, 1]
`